# How to change location where logs are stored?

Tags: log, logging

I am running out of space and would like to move my logs to recover some room on my SSD. My question:

1. I have an SSD (mounted at `/`) and regular hard-drive (mounted at `/mnt/d2`). How can I change it so that my logs (all the logs stored in `/var/log`) are stored somewhere on my other hard-drive (maybe `/mnt/d2/var/log`)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sudo /etc/init.d/rsyslog stop
sudo mv /var/log /mnt/d2/
sudo ln -s /mnt/d2/log /var/log
sudo /etc/init.d/rsyslog start
```

You might want to go ahead and reboot the machine, while you're at it, just in case you have something **other** than `rsyslogd` busily trying to write to logs under /var/log - those won't recover until *they're* restarted as well, which just bouncing the whole box will accomplish nicely.

What we're doing here is, instead of trying to reconfigure everything that might possibly want to write to /var/log, instead just gently redirecting things going there to your other disk.  You can still `cd /var/log` or `less /var/log/syslog` or whatever and have it work just fine, this way, and any new programs that try to log to directories under /var/log directly rather than working through `rsyslogd` will also still work as expected.

Comment: Ah, this is so helpful. Thank you. I thought to potentially do the symlinking, but I got caught up in a mire of symlink subtleties (didn't think to stop `rsyslog`).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to add this as a comment, so here it is as a necro-answer:

It's probably better to mount-bind this in your fstab, copy all the logfiles currently in it to the new partition, then reboot. Then clear the old /var/log. Don't diddle around with symlinks and trying to whack-a-mole running services. You're gonna have a bad time, eventually.

Comment: Showing the code of "mount-bind this in your fstab" would probably help people. Showing the commands to copy the files will also help them.

Comment: As you mentioned this is a comment not a solution to the question. Please add some commands that the user can try

Comment: This is probably really is better than a symlink but care needs to be taken with bind-mounts in fstab with systemd or they will be attempted before the physical drive is mounted.   See this.  Will also provide an example. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216287/how-do-i-set-up-bind-mounts-on-startup-correctly-in-the-systemd-world/324723#324723

Answer (score -1):

It's not dead yet.
edit /etc/fstab add line pointing to new directory

/var/log    /media/usb-stick/log    none    bind    0

Then mount all filesystems in fstab:
mount -a

On Ubuntu to force log rotation:
logrotate -vf /etc/logrotate.conf

To test, but not do anything:
logrotate -vdf /etc/logrotate.conf