# Snap store and snap apps won't run after accidentally deleting /var/log

Tags: mount, snap, log

I was trying to relocate the `/var/log` folder from my SSD drive to my HDD drive referring to [How to change location where logs are stored?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/220358/how-to-change-location-where-logs-are-stored) and I accidentally deleted the whole `/var/log` folder.

And now, few apps don't launch anymore:

Spotify:

```
$ spotify
cannot perform operation: mount --rbind /var/log /tmp/snap.rootfs_cTSELR//var/log: No such file or directory
```

Snap-store:

```
$ snap-store
cannot perform operation: mount --rbind /var/log /tmp/snap.rootfs_2nna30//var/log: No such file or directory
```

And maybe others.

How do I fix the problem?

Comment: Luckily I never did this, so I can't really tell. But what about creating /var/log again? If your box holds valuable data, first make a copy.

Comment: Hello !

Thanks for you answer, in fact it was as simple as this !
-> A log file (broken symbolic link) was present in /var but no /log folder
-> I removed the log file and created a new /log folder
-> Reboot
-> The /log folder is now filled with content, and everything works again !

Thank you again, and sorry for the inconvenience :)
Arthur

Comment: For any out there who happen to have the same problem: you can answer your own question. With a bit more explanation for those who will read it.

Answer (score 1):

A log file (broken symbolic link) was present in `/var` but no `log` folder. I removed the log file and created a new `log` folder and rebooted. The `log` folder is now filled with content, and everything works again!